# Como usar o dplyr dentro de uma função?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Digamos que eu queria criar uma função que use internamente algumas funções do [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) ou de qualquer pacote do [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) que use este tipo de sintaxe.

A título de ilustração:

```
exemplo <- function(df, predicado, sumario) {
  df %>% filter(predicado) %>% 
    summarise(sumario)
}
```

O ideal é que esta função rodasse assim:

```
exemplo(mtcars, cyl == 4, mean(wt))
```

Porém, quando rodo ela assim obtenho

> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : object 'cyl' not found

O resultado esperado é o mesmo obtido quando fazemos

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4) %>% 
  summarise(mean(wt))

#   mean(wt)
# 1 2.285727
```

Então pergunto: como usar o [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) no corpo de uma função sem abrir mão de usar o poder e a simplicidade de sua sintaxe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `dplyr` tem uma sintaxe muito agradável para programarmos interativamente e o tradeoff disso é justamente a programação quando estamos dentro de funções.

O melhor lugar para entender como tudo funciona é [essa vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html).

No seu exemplo, poderia fazer assim:

```
exemplo <- function(df, predicado, sumario) {
  predicado <- enquo(predicado)
  sumario <- enquo(sumario)

  df %>% 
    filter(!! predicado) %>% 
    summarise(!! sumario)
}

exemplo(mtcars, cyl == 4, mean(wt))
```

Essa função `enquo` guarda o argumento passado pelo usuário em algo como se fosse uma string, que depois pode ser usado dentro das funções do `dplyr` precedido de `!!`.

Comment: Fantástico Daniel!

Answer (score 2):

Eu sei que essa pergunta é antiga, mas desde então houveram atualizações no pacote `dplyr` que facilitam muito a programação de funções.

- Utilizamos `{{var}}` para avaliar o valor de uma variável sem `enquo` e `!!`
- Utilizamos `{var} :=` definir um nome a partir de objeto de texto.
- Utilizamos `{{var}} :=`  para definir um nome a partir de um argumento a ser avaliado

```r
library(dplyr)

exemplo <- function(df, predicado, sumario, nome_da_coluna_entre_aspas, nome_da_coluna_sem_aspas) {
  df %>% filter({{predicado}}) %>% 
    summarise("{nome_da_coluna_entre_aspas} média" :=  mean({{sumario}}) ,
              "{{nome_da_coluna_sem_aspas}}_mediana" := median({{sumario}}, na.rm = TRUE))
}

  exemplo(mtcars, cyl == 4, mean(wt),"Teste com aspas", teste_sem_aspas)
#>   Teste com aspas média teste_sem_aspas_mediana
#> 1              2.285727                2.285727
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Mais informações sobre *data masking* e *name injection* podem ser encontradas neste [manual](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). (edit: o manual é o mesmo que está na respota do @Daniel Falbel, só a versão web do pacote).

Comment: Bem notado! M Aurélio